# Symfony2 app/console not generating properties or schema updates for Entity Relationships/Associations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am reading and following along in code what is written in the Symfony2 book on using Database and Doctrine (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html). I have reached the "Entity Relationships/Associations" section but the framework does not seem to be doing what it is meant to be doing. I have added the protected $category field to the Product entity and added the $products field to the Category entity. My Product and Category entities are as below:

**Product:**

```
<?php

namespace mydomain\mywebsiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /*
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

**Category:**

```
<?php

namespace mydomain\mywebsiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /*
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

According to the documentation, if i now execute

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities mydomain
```

the framework should generate the getters/setters for the new category field in Product and for the new products field in Category.

**HOWEVER** when i run the command it supposedly updates the entities but it does not add the properties. I have compared with the backup(~) files and there are no differences. If i add another field (e.g. description2) and add doctrine annotations for persistence to it then it generates the properties. I ignored this at first and manually added the properties for the mapping fields and then executed:

```
$php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

for it to add the new association columns.

**HOWEVER** once again it told me that the metadata and schema were upto date.

I have deleted the app/cache/dev folder and allowed the system to recreate it but it has made no difference.

Can anyone see why the framework is not behaving as described in the documentation??

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have forgotten one star here:

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

it must be

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: After trying different things with absolutely no success i ended up deleting the entire bundle and associated database and starting from scratch again. Second time around things are generated correctly and the database schema is being updated correctly. Such flaky behavior is EXTREMELY POOR of the framework and as mentioned in the comment above is the reason that as a developer i am moving away from Grails. Now i find that symfony2 has the same sort of problems.

When i use a framework i should not need to always keep in the back of my mind whether something is not working because the framework is buggy. This is quite unacceptable for such a mainstream framework and it would seem i am not the only person that has come across such kind of problems. The framework developers should definitely address such issues either by (preferably) resolving them or providing some means of understanding why the framework fails on random occasions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I found the issue is that you can't have two types of definitions..in the book the entity create comand for category also creates a yml configoration so the annotations failed. You must use either annotations or yml or xml or php. Once I removed the yml config and recreated the tables with annotations it worked..be careful and don't use the comnad for the category createion..you will still though get an error that the description is mandatory field :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and I solved it like this:
Delete the "doctrine"-Folder containing the yml-files with the (in your case redundant!) configuration for the entities. Do this ONLY on your test-system for educational purposes.

Some background-information (maybe someone with more experience than me - probably almost everybody here ;o)) can add to this:

- Doctrine preferes YML-Schema configuration over annotations in the entity-class (/** @ORM ... */)
- when working through the book you might have created a blog-entity with YML-Schema configuration a few chapters in before chapter 8 - maybe you played around a little and this YML-Schema is in the same bundle than your chapter 8 exercise
- consequently: Doctrine thinks you want to use YML but it finds only configuation for "anotherEntity" but not for product and category
- OR: you run a few Doctrine commands for testing and choose once (by mistake?) YML and voilà: all further annotation chances will be ignored because i.e. a product.orm.yml exists

Hope that helped. I just started chapter 10 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to generating getters and setters Symfony is just using the ReflectionClass to look if the methods already exist.
It doesn't look what properties are written in the annotation.

Concerning the schema update problem I don't have another solution then resetting the database and creating it from scratch.
I faced this problems a few times but never really found a good solution, it seems Symfony doesn't differ between some properties, which results in not finding any updates.

I don't have a framework by hand now, to look it up. Maybe you can try to find out what schema:update does exactly thus finding the error.

Comment: I have tried resetting the database/starting from scratch...no difference. I have now actually added the category_id column to the product table and created the foreign key manually (which i am assuming is everything that app/console would do) but it makes no difference. When i try and persist a product and category the sql insert statement that it generates is:
INSERT INTO Product (description) VALUES (?). It's completely ignoring the category. This is extremely poor of the framework! I am moving away from GRAILS for this precise reason but it seems symfony2 has the same shortcomings!

Comment: I'm working with people from Sensiolabs Germany directly in the next weeks. I can ask how they try to solve the problem or rather if they are maybe fixing it at the moment.